# highstock issue : pointInterval property is not working when series data set contains date and value?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I used pointInterval property to set interval as 30 days but my data set contains daily data.
That method is not working. chart is displaying all the points.

please check below image for the chart i got
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1wfs7NUcZnGQkk2QWdEbE9ndmM/edit

What is needed is to draw only three points for three months in the above chart.

Following is the code i used to do this.

Note that 'options.data.points' has data set in format of [[date,value],[]....]

`var stockChartData = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: "Stock Chart"
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            yAxis: [
                {
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 2
                    },
                    title: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    lineWidth: 2
                }

            ],
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{data: options.data.points, type: 'line',   pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 *30}]
        };
        stockChart = new Highcharts.StockChart(stockChartData, function (chart) {
        });`

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: So maybe better is setting different tickInterval?

Comment: tickInterval is used to change the interval between  xAxis labels.
Nothing happens to the no of points drawn in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/pointinterval-pointstart/

The data set this example uses is in the format of [value,value,...] (see http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/large-dataset.js).

So when `pointInterval` for a month is used, for example the last two values will be used for the values of last two months. For the same data when `pointInterval` for a year is used, the same last two values is used for the last two years. So the chart doesn't ignore the between values, therefore you will not have for example an average value of the month for day values.

EDIT:

You can use `plotOptions.series.dataGrouping` for grouping the day values in a month:

http://jsfiddle.net/worhscy0/

Comment: Hi Raeen, Thanks for the Reply.
But problem is my data set is having irregular intervals. 
That is why i am using the format of [[date,value],[]....] to specify the exact date of the point.

'pointInterval' property does not work when using that data format.

Comment: I figured you need your data like that, thats why I edited my answer. Please check my last link of `jsfiddle`, it uses `dataGrouping` and you can use that instead of `pointInterval`. Change `month` with `day` and see the difference.

Comment: Thanks Raeen. But in your example when i change the type to line it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?


           `series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: [[
                        'month', // unit name
                        [1] // allowed multiples
                    ]]
                }]`

Comment: It also works with line type, but only when you expand the range (try it, it will show an average of day values in month value). For that you can add `groupPixelWidth` and set it big enough to force the grouping: http://jsfiddle.net/worhscy0/1/

Comment: Thanks Raeen. It is working :). BTW, I'm just curious, what is the 'allowed multiples' means in the units of dataGrouping?

Comment: No problem ;) It says which types (months, days, years) are allowed to be grouped in one datapoint, and how much of them. For example if you set `month` and the value of `2`, this means you are allowing the chart to group the data of two months together. You can also set multiple `allowed multiples`